# Array with nodes at each index

Tags: arrays, swift, random, sprite-kit

i'm creating a game with Sprite Kit in Swift, and i've three nodes (jewels) generated at 3 positions:

```
self.size.width * 1/6  // left
self.size.width * 1/6  // middle
self.size.width * 1/6  // right
```

I've created an array with the three positons to call them randomly:

```
    let randomX = [self.size.width * 1/6, self.size.width * 3/6, self.size.width * 5/6]   // Array with three positions
    let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(randomX.count)))
    let xPos : CGFloat = randomX[randomIndex]
```

I've an other array with the three nodes of jewels:

```
    let randomJewels = [SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "jewel1"), SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "jewel2"), SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "jewel3"),]
```

And I set the position and the size of my generated node:

```
    let jewel1 = randomJewels[Int(arc4random_uniform(3))]
    jewel1.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0)
    jewel1.position = CGPointMake(xPos, self.size.height / 2)
    jewel1.size.width = 40
    jewel1.size.height = 20
    self.addChild(jewel1)
```

The three positions need to be taken by three random node (jewel) but if I generate two other jewelry, they may have the same position, as they may have three different positions.

How can I do so that the jewels hold the three positions? It can not be void position, there is a jewel on every x position! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a jewel you need to remove its image and position from the array so no other jewel can be the same as it:

```
var imageNames=["jewel1","jewel2","jewel3"]//Names of jewel images
var xPositions=[size.width*1/6,size.width*3/6,size.width*5/6]//posible x positions

for i in 0..<xPositions.count {//Create one jewel for every x position

    let imageIndex=Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(imageNames.count)))
    let jewel=SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: imageNames[imageIndex])
    imageNames.removeAtIndex(imageIndex)//remove this image so no other jewel can have it

    let xPositionIndex=Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(xPositions.count)))
    jewel.position=CGPoint(x: xPositions[xPositionIndex], y: size.height/2)
    xPositions.removeAtIndex(xPositionIndex)//remove this position so no other jewel can have it

    //Setup the jewel and add it to the scene

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! But at line who generate the random jewel, i get the error : Missing argument for parameter 'size' in call !

Comment: in the didMoveToView function